# How to call a delegate function from within a custom function?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using a UIPageViewController and I'm trying to call the delegate function:

```
    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
}
```

from within a custom function:

```
func timer () {
//Call UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo here
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's a delegate method and not called without any event. So you should action a event so that this method called.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can call the function you need to set within your view controller the delegate for the instance in question, e.g.

```
let pvc = UIPageViewController()
pvc.delegate = self // assumes that the class adopts UIPageViewController delegate protocol and adheres to it
```

You can then access the delegate and in turn call any methods on that delegate like so:

```
func timer () {
   let pvcDelegate = pvc?.delegate
   // use pvcDelegate followed by function you wish to call
}
```

However it would be unusual to call the delegate methods yourself. Normally it will be the UIPageViewController instance calling the delegate.